# Is it good convention for a class to perform functions on itself?

Tags: oop, class

I've always been taught that if you are doing something *to* an object, that should be an external thing, so one would `Save(Class)` rather than having the object save itself: `Class.Save()`.

I've noticed that in the .Net libraries, it is common to have a class modify itself as with `String.Format()` or sort itself as with `List.Sort()`.

My question is, in strict OOP is it appropriate to have a class which performs functions on itself when called to do so, or should such functions be external and called on an object of the class' type?

Comment: To be fair, String.Format does not modify the string itself.

Comment: @Svend: That's true.  Bad example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question. I have just recently reflected on a very similar issue and was eventually going to ask much the same thing here on SO.

**In OOP textbooks,** you sometimes see examples such as `Dog.Bark()`, or `Person.SayHello()`. I have come to the conclusion that those are bad examples. When you call those methods, you make a dog bark, or a person say hello. However, in the real world, you couldn't do this; a dog decides himself when it's going to bark. A person decides itself when it will say hello to someone. Therefore, these methods would more appropriately be modelled as ***events*** (where supported by the programming language).

You would e.g. have a function `Attack(Dog)`, `PlayWith(Dog)`, or `Greet(Person)` which would trigger the appropriate events.

```
Attack(dog)      // triggers the Dog.Bark event 
Greet(johnDoe)   // triggers the Person.SaysHello event
```

---

**As soon as you have more than one parameter,** it won't be so easy deciding how to best write the code. Let's say I want to store a new item, say an integer, into a collection. There's many ways to formulate this; for example:

```
StoreInto(1, collection)    // the "classic" procedural approach
1.StoreInto(collection)     // possible in .NET with extension methods
Store(1).Into(collection)   // possible by using state-keeping temporary objects
```

According to the thinking laid out above, the last variant would be the preferred one, because it doesn't force an object (the `1`) to do something to itself. However, if you follow that programming style, it will soon become clear that this ***fluent interface***-like code is quite verbose, and while it's easy to read, it can be tiring to write or even hard to remember the exact syntax.

---

**P.S.: Concerning global functions: In the case of .NET** (which you mentioned in your question), you don't have much choice, since the .NET languages do not provide for global functions. I think these would be technically possible with the CLI, but the languages disallow that feature. F# has global functions, but they can only be used from C# or VB.NET when they are packed into a module. I believe Java also doesn't have global functions.

I have come across scenarios where this lack is a pity (e.g. with fluent interface implementations). But ***generally, we're probably better off without global functions***, as some developers might always fall back into old habits, and leave a procedural codebase for an OOP developer to maintain. Yikes.

Btw., in VB.NET, however, you can mimick global functions by using modules. Example:

**`Globals.vb`:**

```
    Module Globals
        Public Sub Save(ByVal obj As SomeClass)
            ...
        End Sub
    End Module
```

**`Demo.vb`:**

```
    Imports Globals
    ...
    Dim obj As SomeClass = ...
    Save(obj)
```

Comment: After re-reading my own answer, I wonder if my reasoning in the first section is at least partly flawed. While `Attack(dog)` seemed right when I wrote it, it isn't clear at all *who* (or *what*) does the attacking; this statement would therefore be more complete as `aggressivePerson.Attack(dog)`, and then we're back to the problem that we were trying to solve in the first place. -- Nevertheless, I still believe this answer provides *some* insight, so I won't re-write it for now.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the answer is "It Depends"... for Persistence of an object I would side with having that behavior defined within a separate repository object. So with your Save() example I might have this:

```
repository.Save(class)
```

However with an Airplane object you may want the class to know how to fly with a method like so:

```
airplane.Fly()
```

This is one of the examples I've seen from Fowler about an aenemic data model. I don't think in this case you would want to have a separate service like this:

```
new airplaneService().Fly(airplane)
```

With static methods and extension methods it makes a ton of sense like in your List.Sort() example. So it depends on your usage pattens. You wouldn't want to have to new up an instance of a ListSorter class just to be able to sort a list like this:

```
new listSorter().Sort(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

In *strict* OOP (Smalltalk or Ruby), all methods belong to an instance object or a class object.  In "real" OOP (like C++ or C#), you will have static methods that essentially stand completely on their own.

Going back to strict OOP, I'm more familiar with Ruby, and Ruby has several "pairs" of methods that either return a modified copy or return the object in place -- a method ending with a `!` indicates that the message modifies its receiver.  For instance:

```
>> s = 'hello'
=> "hello"
>> s.reverse
=> "olleh"
>> s
=> "hello"
>> s.reverse!
=> "olleh"
>> s
=> "olleh"
```

The key is to find some middle ground between pure OOP and pure procedural that works for what you need to do.  A `Class` should do only one thing (and do it well).  Most of the time, that won't include saving itself to disk, but that doesn't mean `Class` shouldn't know how to *serialize* itself to a stream, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what distinction you seem to be drawing when you say "doing something *to* an object".  In many if not most cases, the class itself is the best place to define its operations, as under "strict OOP" it is the only code that has access to internal state on which those operations depend (information hiding, encapsulation, ...).

That said, if you have an operation which applies to several otherwise unrelated types, then it might make sense for each type to expose an interface which lets the operation do most of the work in a more or less standard way.  To tie it in to your example, several classes might implement an interface `ISaveable` which exposes a `Save` method on each.  Individual `Save` methods take advantage of their access to internal class state, but given a collection of `ISaveable` instances, some external code could define an operation for saving them to a custom store of some kind without having to know the messy details.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what information is needed to do the work. If the work is unrelated to the class (mostly equivalently, can be made to work on virtually any class with a common interface), for example, std::sort, then make it a free function. If it must know the internals, make it a member function.

Edit: Another important consideration is performance. In-place sorting, for example, can be miles faster than returning a new, sorted, copy. This is why quicksort is faster than merge sort in the vast majority of cases, even though merge sort is theoretically faster, which is because quicksort can be performed in-place, whereas I've never heard of an in-place merge-sort. Just because it's technically possible to perform an operation within the class's public interface, doesn't mean that you actually should.